# Triggering a modal box on clicking an image using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to trigger a modal box (a button should be inside the modal box) on clicking an image (or icon). Is it possible using HTML and CSS alone ? Or is Js required for this ? If so, how is it done ?

Comment: Have you tried Googling for examples? And no, you need javascript too.

Comment: You have to figure that part our for yourself. Ones you have done the research and decided what to use feel free to post your code if you have issues with the implementation. Please see What Questions [**Are On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones [**Are not On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) as well as [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you know the answer then speak up.. else do your stuff.
I am having doubt, that's y i asked and also a beginner .
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need Javascript for this, but first you should give ur img an id like :
And the you must use bootsrap modal window for this and after that just below line of code will suffice.

Now you can run youre Javascript Code (i use Jquery):

```
<script>
$('#myID').click(function() {
$("#yourmodalid").modal('show') ;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](https://codepen.io/timothylong/pen/HhAer). But you can scroll the back part when the modal is open, which will not look good.

I have simply and easily achieved as below without any third party libraries.
Small scripting needed. In the following code I have used a `button` instead of `img`. You can edit it as if you want.

```js
function toggleDialog()
{
    var dialog = document.getElementById("modal_container");
    dialog.style.display = (dialog.style.display=="none"?"block":"none");
}
```

```css
#modal_container
{
    position:absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #9e9c9c;
}
#modal
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.closebtn
{
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleDialog()">Open</button>
    <div id="modal_container" style="display: none">
        <div id="modal">
            <span class="closebtn" onclick="toggleDialog()">Close</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```