# Pull a List of Data Attributes When Conditions Are Met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've got an HTML table with 10 radio buttons in each cell (besides the header cells). When your done selecting radio buttons you click the *Export to Excel* button at the bottom. This will download an Excel file for you with your radio button selections.

Now what I'm trying to do is detect how many radio buttons are selected in the first 5 cells with radio buttons in each row. If it's between `1` & `5` I want a simple `<div>` popup to appear with the list of rows that meet these conditions with their `data-id` attribute. On that popup I just need it to have a *Okay* & *Cancel* button. When the user clicks *Okay* then it downloads the Excel file; otherwise if the user clicks the *Cancel* button it doesn't download the Excel file.

I understand that I need to insert something like this into my `tableToExcel` function:

`var checkedItems = row.find(":checked:not(:radio[name='attendance'])")
if (checkedItems.length >= 1 && < 5) {
enter code here
}`

And then run the rest of the `tableToExcel` code when the user selects *Okay* on the popup but I'm unsure on how to call the `data-id`'s of the `<tr>`'s that meet the conditions and assemble a list of them for the popup.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ChippeRock/ukbxL5uz/) and the snippet is below:

```js
var overall = $('#overall');

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').change(function(e) {
    var row = $(this).closest('.item');
    var checkedItems = row.find(":checked:not(:radio[name='attendance'])")
    if (e.target.name != "attendance") {

      if (checkedItems.length == 5) {
        row.find("td.overall").html(getOverall(checkedItems));
      }
    } else {
      row.find("td.attendance").html("x " + parseFloat($(this).val() / 10).toFixed(1));
    }
  })

  function getOverall(_checkedItems) {
    var total = 0;
    _checkedItems.each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    return total;
  }


});

var tableToExcel = (function() {

  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}<\/x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/><\/x:WorksheetOptions><\/x:ExcelWorksheet><\/x:ExcelWorksheets><\/x:ExcelWorkbook><\/xml><![endif]--><\/head><body><table>{table}<\/table><\/body><\/html>',
    base64 = function(s) {
      return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    },
    format = function(s, c) {
      return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
        return c[p];
      })
    }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) {
      table = document.getElementById(table)
    }
    var cloned = $('#copyTable').clone().appendTo('.hidden_table')
    cloned.find('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + span').remove();

    var ctx = {
      worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
      table: cloned.html()
    }
    cloned.remove();
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
  }
})();
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 115%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.hidden_table {
  /*display:none*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="copyTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Skating</th>
      <th>Shooting</th>
      <th>Passing</th>
      <th>Puck Control</th>
      <th>Game Understanding</th>
      <th>Attendance</th>
      <th>Overall</th>
      <th>Attendance <br>Factor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="item" data-id="1">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="overall" id="overall">
      </td>
      <td class="attendance" id="attendance"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="2">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="overall" id="overall">
      </td>
      <td class="attendance" id="attendance"></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="hidden_table" id="hidden_table"></div>
<div align="center">
  <input type="button" onclick="tableToExcel('copyTable', 'Player_scores')" value="Export to Excel">
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the entire row as table in the modal or just their data-id values as string in the modal ?

Comment: @VigneshRaja Well the ultimate goal was to use these `data-id` values and use them to display the rows in the popup so if you want to do that I'm perfectly fine with it. I am also fine with simply using the `data-id` values as just kind of a string/list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works.

I just displayed the `data-id` in the modal dialog.

To know how I created modal dialog, [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48166464/triggering-a-modal-box-on-clicking-an-image-using-html-and-css/48167014#48167014)

```js
var overall = $('#overall');
var rows = [];
var toggleDialog = function()
{
    var dialog = document.getElementById("modal_container");
    dialog.style.display = (dialog.style.display=="none"?"block":"none");
}

var populateModalData = function()
{
    $("#modaldata").html(rows.join(","));
    toggleDialog();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').change(function(e) {
    var row = $(this).closest('.item');
    var checkedItems = row.find(":checked:not(:radio[name='attendance'])")
    if (e.target.name != "attendance")
    {
        var id = row.data("id");
        if (checkedItems.length == 5)
        {
            if(rows.indexOf(id)<0) rows.push(id);
            row.find("td.overall").html(getOverall(checkedItems));
            populateModalData();
        }
        else
        {
            if(rows.indexOf(id)>-1) rows.splice(rows.indexOf(id),1); 
        }
    } else {
      row.find("td.attendance").html("x " + parseFloat($(this).val() / 10).toFixed(1));
    }
  })

  function getOverall(_checkedItems) {
    var total = 0;
    _checkedItems.each(function() {
      total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    return total;
  }
});

var tableToExcel = (function() {

  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
    template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}<\/x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/><\/x:WorksheetOptions><\/x:ExcelWorksheet><\/x:ExcelWorksheets><\/x:ExcelWorkbook><\/xml><![endif]--><\/head><body><table>{table}<\/table><\/body><\/html>',
    base64 = function(s) {
      return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))
    },
    format = function(s, c) {
      return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {
        return c[p];
      })
    }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) {
      table = document.getElementById(table)
    }
    var cloned = $('#copyTable').clone().appendTo('.hidden_table')
    cloned.find('input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) + span').remove();

    var ctx = {
      worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
      table: cloned.html()
    }
    cloned.remove();
    window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
  }
})();
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 115%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.hidden_table {
  /*display:none*/
}

/*modal start*/
#modal_container
{
    position:fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #9e9c9c;
    z-index:100000;
}
#modal
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.closebtn
{
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    right:10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.buttongroup
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
}
/* modal end */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="copyTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Team</th>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Skating</th>
      <th>Shooting</th>
      <th>Passing</th>
      <th>Puck Control</th>
      <th>Game Understanding</th>
      <th>Attendance</th>
      <th>Overall</th>
      <th>Attendance <br>Factor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="item" data-id="1">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="overall" id="overall">
      </td>
      <td class="attendance" id="attendance"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="item" data-id="2">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="skating" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="shooting" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="passing" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="puck_control" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="team_play" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="">
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="1"><span>1</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="2"><span>2</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="3"><span>3</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="4"><span>4</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="5"><span>5</span>
          <br>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="6"><span>6</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="7"><span>7</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="8"><span>8</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="9"><span>9</span>
          <input type="radio" name="attendance" value="10"><span>10</span>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td class="overall" id="overall">
      </td>
      <td class="attendance" id="attendance"></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="hidden_table" id="hidden_table"></div>
<div align="center">
  <input type="button" onclick="populateModalData()" value="Export to Excel">
</div>

<div id="modal_container" style="display: none">
    <div id="modal">
        <span class="closebtn" onclick="toggleDialog()">Close</span>
        <div id="modaldata"></div>
        <div class="buttongroup">
            <button onclick="tableToExcel('copyTable', 'Player_scores')">Okay</button>
            <button onclick="toggleDialog()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to have the code necessary to do what I want but when you click the *Export to Excel* button it does the same thing as my original code does. How do you connect the *Export to Excel* button so that the modal dialog box actually shows up when it's clicked?

Comment: U want the modal to be shown on clicking the export button ?

Comment: Updated the answer. Now modal will be shown on clicking the export button. If you don't want the modal to be shown on selecting 5 radio buttons in a row, just remove the `populateModalData();` line from the `if` condition.

Comment: After making a couple modifications to your code I got the result I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand your question correctly, you want to obtain the `data-id` in the `change` handler?

If yes, than you happen to have a reference to the surrounding `<tr>`:

```js
  $(':radio').change(function(e) {
    var row = $(this).closest('.item');
    var checkedItems = row.find(":checked:not(:radio[name='attendance'])")
    if (e.target.name != "attendance") {

      if (checkedItems.length == 5) {
        row.find("td.overall").html(getOverall(checkedItems));
      }
    } else {
      row.find("td.attendance").html("x " + parseFloat($(this).val() / 10).toFixed(1));
    }
  console.log('data-id=', row[0].dataset.id)
  })
```

so `row[0]` is the actual `<tr>` element and `row[0].dataset.id` the value of its `data-id` attribute.

Comment: This only works for the snippet. It also records the data-id every single time you click a radio button. Rather than recording the `data-id`'s when you click the *Export to Excel* button and only then recording `data-id`'s that had between 1 & 4 of the first 5 column's radio buttons selected.